# Creating FireFox Plugin

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, plugins, bho

please let me start by explaining my situation.

My intention is to be able to create a plugin that will redirect the user their home page if he/she tries to navigate to a forbidden website. I have been able to successfully and effectively create this as a Browser Helper Object in IE, which leads me to my new goal: to be able to do the same thing in Firefox.

I may very likely be wrong, but from what I have spent reading, an extension in Firefox enabled users to freely and easily install, modify, and delete the extensions, while a plugin has the ability to be installed without a user's knowledge.

I created the Browser Helper Object with the intent of being as seamless and hidden as possible, the .dll file that will be my BHO is previously registered through cmd. In this case i do not want the user to have any control to see or change anything that is happening when he/she is accessing a specific site.

My question is not how to create one, but if it is possible to reproduce the desired events in a plugin. I have not come across any articles, tutorials, or other resources that have hinted at this possibility. Will I be able to reproduce my BHO in a plugin? Or are there other various ways in which an extension can be hidden from the user?

Thank you very much for the time, Your replies are absolutely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Firefox has Addons and plugins.  Addons are written in a version of javascript with some special functionalities to allow operations like reading/writing files, modifying the page/requests, etc.  Plugins like flash, java, or the DIVX plugin are displayed as part of the webpage.  It sounds like you want to make an addon.

Keep in mind, users can disable or uninstall addons and plugins quite easily from firefox.

It sounds like you might be better doing this with a proxy that analyses requests like websense.

If you don't want to go the proxy route, maybe a tool that uses winpcap (windows version of libpcap) to monitor all outgoing network traffic that contains web requests (GET, POST, etc) and simply block them that way?  You could create one program that worked for all browsers and make it harder to uninstall